# Python faster import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a question regarding the python import part.
Every time I am running my script python has to load up a bunch of import stuff.
Is there a way to skip this part in the way you can do that with jupyter notebook?

Thanks for your help!

I tried using Jupyter notebook but that is actually not my favorite coding environment.

Comment: Are you asking how to accomplish something in an undefined environment the way it is done in a particular (presumably different) one?

Comment: that's called interactive mode .... you can do that in almost any IDE.

Comment: How long do the imports take? Is it actually a problem?

Comment: Python does optimize module imports to some extent. The first time you import something, it is compiled to bytecode. That bytecode is saved to disk alongside the imported file so it can be reused the next time it's imported. If by some chance you don't have write permission to that location, Python will need to compile your imported modules every time you run your script. In this case (assuming Python 3.8 or later) set the environment variable `PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX` to a directory where you have write access.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script, add "python -O". It will perform an optimized build. However it will disable some features like the built-in debug var.

You can always use the "import time" library to measure the time taken by each import and figure out if what you're trying is effective.

Hope this will help you

Comment: The `-O` flag doesn't actually make anything run faster, except to the extent that it strips out debug code.